# Schedule a rake task for a certain time in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, newsletter

I need to send an email newsletter with rails on a certain date in the future (not recurring). Is there any way I can do this with some kind of rake scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the delayed_job gem and do something like this:

```
Notifier.delay(run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).signup(@user)
```

You can get more information from the readme:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job